# Using own icons in header using html

Tags: html, css, email, templates, icons

I am creating email templates.

In the header, there should be four icons: twitter,facebook,linkedin and google+ icon and a hotline number icon in which we designed ourselves.

How to use our own icons in html? kinda stuck here. any help appreciated.

```html
<div><div><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="text-align: center; width: 100%; font-size: 10pt; border-collapse: collapse">
<tbody style="margin: 0">

<tr style="height: 100px">
<td colspan="14" style="background-color: rgb(41, 62, 151)">
<img src="link from image in zoho crm is here" style="width: 100%">
</td>

<td colspan="14" style="background-color: rgb(41, 62, 151)">
"><img src="link from image in zoho crm is here " style="width: 250px; vertical-align: top">
</td>

</tr>

</tbody></table></div><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="text-align: center; width: 100%; font-size: 10pt">
<tbody><tr>
<td colspan="2" style="background-color: rgb(41, 62, 151); height: 100%; width: 5%">
<br>
</td>

<td colspan="10" style="background-color: rgb(41, 62, 151); height: 100%; width: 90%; padding: 30px 100px">

<p style="text-align: center; font-size: 35px"><span style="color: white; font-family: Callibri, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 35px; text-align: center">some text here</span><b style="color: rgb(42, 61, 151); font-family: Callibri, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: large; text-align: center"></b>
</p>
</td>

<td colspan="2" style="background-color: rgb(41, 62, 151); height: 100px; width: 5%">
<br>
</td>

</tr>


</tbody>
</table>
```

[Sample Picture of header here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLOVJ.jpg)

Comment: Do you have any code for us to work with? It's difficult to address any problems you have without seeing what we're trying to work with.

Comment: here is an example of my code that I posted in my Gist https://gist.github.com/sjvelasquez/d7f1681dc57a99a130428ae01e845ce5

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about html in sent emails, you can include images in that html with `<img src="google.com/image.jpg" >` and they will appear. Find the images from the internet, then include the links in the html.

Comment: hmm what I mean is creating a header in an email template that has social media icons using html

Comment: I posted what the header should look like

Comment: That's ok. Just put real link in the images and you're done.